# Why doesn't Clara Kalliam return to her parents or family when her husband's name is disgraced?

Tags: the-dagger-and-the-coin

So I just finished reading *The King's Blood*, the second book in the [Dagger and Coin](http://www.danielabraham.com/books-by-daniel-abraham/the-dagger-and-the-coin/) series by [Daniel Abraham](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Abraham_%28author%29).

I am wondering why Clara Kalliam, when her husband Dawson is killed by Geder Palliako and the Kalliam family name is disgraced, does not even consider the thought of going back to her original family. She was also born in a noble family (not Kalliam), as she herself reminds Dawson once. I think at some point in the books her girl's name was even mentioned. Yet after her husband is disgraced and then her son Jorey and daughter-in-law Sabiha throw her out of Lord Skestinin's house, she has no home to go to. She is later taken in by Vincen Coe, who was her servant once. In the scene where she stands on the Autumn Bridge and weeps, she thinks "*Without a home to go to, without a friend to rely on, she was reduced to the aspect of a madwoman wailing on the bridge, and she found the role fit well enough.*"

If she has a noble family with an estate somewhere, wouldn't that be a place to turn to? Would her family not take her in instead of letting her live on the streets? Or if she does not have any family anymore (which seems unlikely), you would think this kind of thing would have been mentioned somewhere. Or did I just miss something? I am just confused that this possibility never pops up at all, anywhere.

Comment: Tag created for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only had the most cursory glance at the novels but four things immediately struck me;

1) After her husband is disgraced, she recognises that she's tainted by association. Returning to her old family home would likely put them in immediate jeopardy, even assuming they weren't one of the 30 noble families "destroyed" in the rebellion.

2) She is described as having been "raised at court" and "taken from the temple before her twentieth nameday", both of which would suggest that she was orphaned. The total lack of any reference to her parents would seem to support this.

3) In the first book, the only relative mentioned is her cousin Phelia Ebbinghaus and her husband Lord Maas. Both of them die before the end of the book and their lands are taken by the king. My guess would be that *her family's* lands and estates were combined with Lord Maas' holdings which now belong to the Crown.

4) **She's being dramatic.** It's clear that she doesn't want to leave her family. Her son is providing her with a stipend sufficient to pay her room and board (with a former servant) and her relationship with him is improving.

Comment: Yes, you make some very good points. Still it would be nice to learn some more about Clara's past. Let's see -- I have the third book to go :)

Comment: Don't forget to post your own answer if you come across something better. I literally downloaded the first couple of books, flicked through and then deleted them.

Comment: If you like contemporary epic sword-and-sorcery fantasy literature, I can recommend this saga. While it doesn't exhibit the excellent quality of masterpieces like George Martin's *A Song of Ice and Fire* or Patrick Rothfuss's *The Kingkiller Chronicle*, it's definitely not cheap fantasy either. It is well-written and highly entertaining. I am devouring them :)